# Why is my PayPal smart button not loading the payment window when clicked? (JavaScript error)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I created a website using WordPress and WooCommerce (bodysciencesupps.com):

- I'm using PayPal checkout as my payment method and everything
  is working correctly during a regular cart checkout.
- When I enable the smart button feature [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk8ua.png) the buttons appear on the
  product pages, but when clicked the PayPal portal popup window appears
  for a split second and then closes.
- I checked my console and this error is thrown when the smart button
  is clicked:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: TypeError: window.wc_ppec_generate_cart is not a function
> at wc-gateway-ppec-smart-payment-buttons.js:104
> at new ZalgoPromise (promise.js:41)
> at Object.payment (wc-gateway-ppec-smart-payment-buttons.js:101)
> at hacks.js:182
> at new ZalgoPromise (promise.js:41)
> at ParentComponent.payment (hacks.js:151)
> at Function._try [as try] (promise.js:409)
> at ParentComponent.payment (component.jsx:432)
> at Object.resultValue (props.js:88)
> at serialize.js:34
> at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
> at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
> at messageListener (index.js:140)
> ```

I'm not sure where to go from here to solve this. I have to keep the smart button disabled because my site is live, but I really need to use the smart buttons. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that this function is not called before the script which contains it is loaded (in case it is loaded asynchronousely).

Comment: This would appear to be a problem with WooCommerce's JS not loading completely.  Try reinstalling the plugin.  Make sure tehre are no JS errors in the console on page load.  Check for conflicts with other wordpress plugins.  Also consider trying the plugin on a base Wordpress + WooCommerce install, which should work. Something is conflicting / not loading properly.